# CiviCRM upgrade from 4.6 to 5.3 > [warning] Both parameters should have an equal number of elements Relationship.php:2222

Tags: upgrade

Subject says it all. Just wondering if anyone has seen something like this before?

Comment: I've seen it but haven't yet dug into what is generating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is displayed when some Names for a relationship type do not match the Labels.

For example in civicrm_relationship_type table you may have something like

name_a_b = Mayor
name_b_a = Mayor
label_a_b = Mayor of
label_b_a = Mayor is

You can correct these either in SQL or via the UI

---

UPDATE

To identify the rows causing the issue

```
select name_a_b, label_a_b, name_b_a, label_b_a from civicrm_relationship_type where name_a_b <> label_a_b;
select name_b_a, label_b_a from civicrm_relationship_type where name_b_a <> label_b_a;
```

**To fix we want to set the name = to the label**

Make a temporary backup - this will be dropped when you log out of mysql.

```
create temporary table temp_civicrm_relationship_type as select * from civicrm_relationship_type;
update civicrm_relationship_type set name_b_a = label_b_a where name_b_a <> label_b_a;
update civicrm_relationship_type set name_a_b = label_a_b where name_a_b <> label_a_b;
```

Confirm that the number of rows updated matches result of the query.

(nb I just grabbed this from a ticket in our own system but hope it is helpful in your case)

Comment: A tiny addendum: it seems SQL is the only place for edits, since it looks different via CiviCRM GUI (at civicrm/admin/reltype?reset=1) and in, say, phpmyadmin.

Comment: Just wondering what do we change to stay safe: name or label? One of this might be used/hard-coded somewhere (across templates for example)  so we may break things. I'd say it is labels, but not really sure. Besides, making labels the same as names might not always have a semantic sense.